# Rand(), srand() 1to1 replacement using urandom

Tags: c, linux, random, coverity

I am currently playing around with coverity and it yells about rand() calls

```
CID 52583 (#1 of 1): Don't call (DC.WEAK_CRYPTO)
dont_call: rand() should not be used for security related applications, as linear congruential algorithms are too easy to break.
```

Is there an easy drop in replacement using urandom to return numbers in the same range as rand() did?

Comment: I suppose the answer depends on what range rand() returns on your system.  You'd know that better than us...  (It's RAND_MAX if you want to tell us).

Comment: Are you using it in a security related application where it matters if the `rand` implementation (not necessarily a linear congruential algorithm, but almost certainly not cryprographically secure) is easy to break?

Comment: Before you shop for an implementation that meets your requirements, you need to work out what your requirements are.

Comment: Note that a drop-in replacement that creates functions named `rand()` and `srand()` will likely still be complained about by Coverity.  You'd have to use different names to persuade it that you're not using the standard versions.

Comment: thx guys - yeah actually i would need a function to get rand value from within a given range - and it is not a security related part of the application - its just to randomize timing information. e.g: i would like to have a function my_random(0, MAX_RAND) - and get a value betwen the range 0-MAX_RAND

Comment: C specifies `RAND_MAX` (which it at least 32767) as `rand()` inclusively returns `[0...RAND_MAX]`.  Is your `MAX_RAND <= RAND_MAX`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might try something like this:
I've used it many times and seems to work very well.

```
void SeedRandomNumGenerator()
{
    unsigned int seed;
    int fd;

    fd = open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY);
    if( fd )
    {
        read(fd, &seed, sizeof(seed));
        close(fd);
        srandom( seed );
    }
}

/*
    return a proper random number that uses the uniform distribution
    of numbers returned by random() -- this is far better than
    simply doing random() % limit
    According to calculations, random() will at most be called twice
    and usually only once per call to random_lim()

    returns int between 0 and limit
    so if you want a random number between 1-10 inclusive the call would 
    look like this:     random_lim(9)+1
*/
int random_lim(int limit)
{
    int divisor = RAND_MAX/(limit+1);
    int retval;

    do
    { 
        retval = random() / divisor;
    }while (retval > limit);

    return( retval );
}
```

EDIT: If you want to get rid of the call to random() this [link](http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~selinger/random/) provides an implementation of random() that behaves the same as random().

Comment: thx this looks nice - but it still ends up using random() and the warning in coverity wont go away - any other idea? - or maybe a way to suppress the warnings

Comment: Note: `int divisor = RAND_MAX/(limit+1);` is a problem when `limit == INT_MAX` or `limit > RAND_MAX`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to suppress the Coverity warnings about `rand()` in my code, where its use is **not** security-related, I've provided a `modeling.c` Coverity [modeling file](https://scan.coverity.com/tune#writing-model) to Coverity, to tell Coverity to ignore that function, *e.g.*:

```
/* libc functions. */

int rand(void) {
  /* ignore */
}

long random(void) {
  /* ignore */
}

void srand(unsigned int seed) {
  /* ignore */
}
```

For other examples of suppressions along these lines, I often look at Python's [Coverity](https://docs.python.org/devguide/coverity.html) docs.

Hope this helps!